# How to make printing faster in C#

Tags: c#

I am new to C# windows forms. I built EPOS software where you can print the receipt through a receipt printer.

I use Epson TM receipt printer serial connector to print the receipt. The printer is connected to the windows PC and it prints but the problem is that it prints the test page very slow and that means my Epos software will use same printer and accordingly it will print slow. 
if I use USB Printer the test page is very fast but when I use serial printer the test page comes out very slow.

I have seen many windows Epos Apps which use serial printer and these Epos Apps print fast on same serial printer and I think they program the Epos to print faster.

My question is:

Anyone knows how can I make the printing process faster via C# code? or if there is other solution I am happy to hear.

Comment: How are you doing the printing? Bitmap or sending text directly to the printer? That’s one huge difference in speed at least

Comment: @Sami Kuhmonen  I am using Crystal Reports.

Comment: There are two basic ways to print something on a POS printer.  One is to treat it like a normal printer and use its printer driver.  It uses the printer in graphics mode, every single pixel requires one bit of data.  There is a lot of data.  The other is using the native printing language, Epsom escape codes, bypassing the printer driver.  Every character (many pixels) requires one byte of data.  A lot less data.  You have no choice when you use CR.

Comment: Look for OPOS, or RawPrinterHelper (not sure if this is still a thing, but I used it 5 years ago and it's super fast, with a lot of control)